# Assign a value into thymeleaf <div> using javascript

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

First I have a  on thymeleaf:

`<div th:id=""d_+${model.id}" />`

Now I want to assign a value into this  but in a javascript function. How can I get this :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this and tell me if this worked for you

inside the javascript function do this

```
var modelId = [[${model.id}]] ;
$("#" + 'd_' + modelId).val("the value that you want to set")
```